# Java locking other critical sections

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a static method which will be accessed by multiple threads, as shown below. What I would like to do is allow any number of threads to execute block 1 so long as no thread is currently executing block 2, and vice versa. Basically, the execution of one block puts a lock on the other block but not itself. The ReentrantReadWriteLock somewhat does what I want, since I can place a read lock around block 1 and a write lock around block 2, but it's still limited in that I can't have multiple threads executing block 2 at the same time. Any suggestions?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    ...
    public static void someMethod()
    {
        ...
        if(someCondition == true)            //Begin block 1
        {
           doSomething();
        }                                    //End block 1

        else if(someCondition == false)      //Begin block 2
        {
           doSomething();
        }                                    //End block 2
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: use a `volatile boolean` flag

Comment: @parsaporahmad That doesn't establish critical regions and will result in concurrency errors here.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to create your own synchronization object:  It would have methods: enterA(), leaveA(), enterB(), leaveB(); and it would have a mutex, a condition var, and attributes aCount, and bCount.

```
enterA:
    lock mutex
    wait on condition var until bCount is zero
    increment aCount
    unlock mutex

leaveA:
    lock mutex
    decrement aCount
    notify condition var if aCount==0
    unlock mutex
```

enterB() and leaveB() would be similar, but would inc/dec bCount, and wait for aCount==0.